# AWS CDK ignores taskSubnets selection

Tags: flask, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I have a flask app which I'm trying to deploy into a landing zone, using CDK (Typescript, v2.5.0) as a Fargate instance.

The landing zone an existing VPC which I need to use, with Isolated and Private subnets.

I've tried every combination I can think of to get the load balancer (tried both application- and network-balanced) to use the Isolated subnets, but nothing has worked.

The error I get from `cdk synth` is

```
deploy/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts:401
      throw new Error(`There are no '${subnetType}' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: ${availableTypes}`);
            ^
*Error: There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Isolated*
```

Here's my code:

```js
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import { Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import * as ec2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";
import * as ecs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs";
import * as ecsp from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns";

export class DeployStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {

    super(scope, id, props);

    const defaultnonprodVPC = "existing-vpc";

    const defaultVPC = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this,
      "defaultVPC",
      {
        isDefault: false,
        vpcId: defaultnonprodVPC,
        tags: { "aws-cdk:subnet-type": "isolated" }
      }
    );

    const knownIsolatedSubnets = defaultVPC.isolatedSubnets;

    const monitoringSubnets = defaultVPC.selectSubnets(
      {
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
      }
    );

    const networkBalancedFargateService = new ecsp.NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService(this,
      "ConnectorMonitorService", {
        memoryLimitMiB: 512,
        desiredCount: 1,
        cpu: 256,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset("../src")
        },
        taskSubnets:
          {
            subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
          },
        vpc: defaultVPC
      });
  }
}
```

Changing the `taskSubnets` to any of

```
{ subnets: { knownIsolatedSubnets } }
```

or

```
subnetGroupName: "subnet-existing-subnet-name"
```

or

```
monitoringSubnets
```

makes no difference to `cdk synth`. Setting `assignPublicIp: false` doesn't change things either.

What am I doing wrong, or missing?

Comment: Is `cdk.context.json` caching the expected vpc and subnet [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html)?  Also, double-check that you are compiling typescript with `tsc` before synth.

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService` has a property `publicLoadBalancer` which is `true` by default. This makes the Load Balancer internet-facing, which is not correct in your case. You need to set it to `false` so that private or isolated subnets work.

[Documentation for NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService.html#publicloadbalancer)